# Asp.Net MVC3 Page Curl

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

How would I implement this:
http://elliottkember.com/sexy_curls.html

In a ASP.Net MVC 3 web application?
My _Layout.cshtml page head tag source looks like this:

```
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src=@Url.Content("~/turn/turn.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("~/turn/turn.css")"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#target').fold();
});
```

And then I have an image tag in the body:

```
<img id="target" src=@Url.Content("~/turn/code.png") alt="blah"/>
```

I only get it to show the entire background image, but no curl.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some double quotes here:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/turn/turn.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
            ^
```

here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/turn/turn.css")" type="text/css" />
                            ^
```

and here:

```
<img id="target" src="@Url.Content("~/turn/code.png")" alt="blah"/>
                     ^                               ^
```

Comment: Thanks, the whole background image doesnt show in the right hand side anymore, but the fold images does not show and nothing is draggable

Comment: @Pete, maybe you have other errors. Make sure your HTML is valid. You could use the [W3 validator service](http://validator.w3.org/). Also make sure you don't have javascript errors. FireBug could be useful.

Comment: Thanks Darin, I've noticed in the turn.js file there is a directory variable that is set to "." How would I point it to my turn directory under my root folder if I'm accessing it from the View/Shared folder?

Comment: @Pete, try like this: `$('#target').fold({ directory: '@Url.Content("~/turn")' });`.